# Ajax laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте.
Совсем недавно начал учить фреймворк laravel 5.3, и возникли первые трудности, гуглил пол дня но толком ничего не нашел по такому, казалось бы, легчайшему вопросу, в общем не могу понять как сделать форму обратной связи через ajax, т.е. что писать вообще в строку url: все обработчики в классе DataController.php, а как дать аяксу понять где они обрабатываются?

Comment: [Маршрутизация в Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простой пример. В любом view-е

```
<form action="">
{{csrf_field()}}
<label>Введите Ваше имя</label>
<input type="text" name="hello" id="hello">
<button id="text" type="button">push me</button>
</form>

<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#text").click(function(){
      var n=$("#hello").val();
      $.ajax({
      url:'/ajaxtest', //url в роуте
      type:'POST',
      data:{mname: n},

      success:function(data){
      alert(data);//В случае успеха    
}
},

    error: function (data) {
    alert(data);//В случае ошибки
    }

});
});
});
</script>
```

В роуте

```
Route::post('ajaxtest','Demo@save')->name('ajaxtest'); //ajaxtest дял url Demo-controler, @save функция
```

В контролере

```
public function save(Request $post){
    $hello="Привет".$post['mname'];
    return response()->json($hello);
}
```

Результат alert Привет + Ваше имя